# Filter rows based on multiple conditions using dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:2,each = 10), threshold = rep(1:10,times = 2))
```

I want to filter out the first rows when `threshold` >= 2 and `threshold` is >= 4 for each `loc.id`. I did this:

```
df %>% group_by(loc.id) %>% dplyr::filter(row_number() == which.max(threshold >= 2),row_number() == which.max(threshold >= 4))
```

I expected a dataframe like this:

```
      loc.id threshold
        1       2
        1       4
        2       2
        2       4
```

But it returns me an empty dataframe

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I think you may need to change the condition to `>=` for the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the condition, we can `slice` the rows from concatenating the two `which.max` index, get the `unique` (if there are only cases where threshold is greater than 4, then both the conditions get the same index)

```
df %>%
    group_by(loc.id) %>%
    filter(any(threshold >= 2)) %>% # additional check
    #slice(unique(c(which.max(threshold > 2), which.max(threshold > 4))))
    # based on the expected output
    slice(unique(c(which.max(threshold >= 2), which.max(threshold >= 4))))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   loc.id [2]
#  loc.id threshold
#   <int>     <int>
#1      1         2
#2      1         4
#3      2         2
#4      2         4
```

Note that there can be groups where there are no values in threshold greater than or equal to 2.  We could keep only those groups

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't what you want, assign the df below a name and use it to filter your dataset.

````
df %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  filter(threshold ==2 | threshold==4)
#>   loc.id threshold
#> 1      1         2
#> 2      1         4
#> 3      2         2
#> 4      2         4
```
````